# Como inserir dados de um textarea no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

Tenho um form com um `textarea` e não estou conseguindo mandar os dados digitados nele para o banco `MySQL`. Como faço?

**formulario.php**

```
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action = cadastro.php>

<textarea id="text_descricao" name="text_descricao" maxlength="800" cols="60" rows="15"; style="resize: none"></textarea>

<input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar"/>
```

**cadastro.php**

```
<?php

    $descricao = $_POST['text_descricao'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mensagens VALUES ";

    $sql .= "('$descricao')";

    mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");

    mysqli_close($conexao);

?>
```

Comment: Qual o erro? Qual a estrutura da sua tabela?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Meu caro tente fazer dessa forma

```
<?php
    //Seta os campos e valores seguindo a ordem que existe na tabela

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mensagens (descricao) VALUES ";
    $sql .= "('$descricao')";

    //ou então dessa forma
    //ASSIM VOCÊ PASSA PARA CONSULTA SOMENTE OS CAMPOS DESEJADOS OU SEJA 
    //SE HOUVER
    //MAIS CAMPOS EM SUA TABELA MAS NÃO TERA INFORMAÇÕES PARA ELE NO 
    //MOMENTO EM  QUE SALVAR A MENSAGEM PODE FAZER ASSIM.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mensagens SET ";
    $sql .= "descricao = '$descricao' ";
?>
```